# Emacs on Window 7 saving files to VirtualStore directory

Tags: windows-7, emacs, uac

I've recently installed ClojureBox on a Windows 7 machine after using it on a different, XP machine for a while.  When I created and saved a file, it wasn't being saved where I expected, but to the \Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\VirtualStore directory.  This happened as long as I wasn't running emacs as the local administrator.

A Google search returned only a couple of hits, and with nothing I could really apply other than to run emacs as a local admin.

Any other way to get around this?  Is there a windows setting, or something I could configure in emacs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click Emacs and "run as Administrator" which I expect will get annoying quickly. Further, if you launch other apps from inside it you might be misled about the behaviour of those apps under normal circumstances. A better approach would be to save your files somewhere other than under Program Files or the root of C, thus avoiding virtualization.

Comment: That was the problem.  I was saving the files to a folder underneath the Clojure Box folder, which is installed in Program Files.

Comment: You can just move that folder underneath Clojure and create a symlink.